# How to resolve Guava dependency issue while submitting Uber Jar to Google Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using maven shade plugin to build Uber jar for submitting it as a job to google dataproc cluster.
Google have installed Apache Spark 2.0.2 Apache Hadoop 2.7.3 on their cluster.

Apache spark 2.0.2 uses 14.0.1 of com.google.guava and apache hadoop 2.7.3 uses 11.0.2, these both should be in the classpath already.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <!--  
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    -->
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com.google.guava:guava:*</exclude>                                 
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I include guava 16.0.1 jar in shade plugin i get this Eexception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {10.148.0.3}:9042
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:163)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:82)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:322)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:342)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:50)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:137)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:232)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1913)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1134)
at com.test.scala.CreateVirtualTable$.main(CreateVirtualTable.scala:47)
at com.test.scala.CreateVirtualTable.main(CreateVirtualTable.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initAsync(Connection.java:177)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:731)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:251)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:199)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1414)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:393)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:156)

... 32 more
17/05/10 09:07:36 INFO
```

And If i exclude Guava 16.0.1 then it throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeParameter
at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.checkGuava(SanityChecks.java:50)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.check(SanityChecks.java:36)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:67)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.clusterBuilder(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:35)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:92)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:82)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:322)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:342)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:50)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:137)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:232)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1913)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1134)
at com.test.scala.CreateVirtualTable$.main(CreateVirtualTable.scala:47)
at com.test.scala.CreateVirtualTable.main(CreateVirtualTable.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 38 more
17/05/11 08:24:00 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@edc6a5d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}
17/05/11 08:24:00 INFO com.datastax.spark.connector.util.SerialShutdownHooks: Successfully executed shutdown hook: Clearing session cache for C* connector
```

So what can be the problem here ?
is classloader on dataproc picking guava 11.0.2 from hadoop ?
as guava 11.0.2 does not have class com/google/common/reflect/TypeParameter .
All the google dataproc developers watching this tag please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited**: See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc for a fully worked example for Maven and SBT.

**Original Answer**
When I make uber jars to run on Hadoop / Spark / Dataproc, I often use whichever version of guava suits my needs and then use a shade relocation which allows the different versions to co-exist without issue:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      <artifactSet>
          <includes>
            <include>com.google.guava:*</include>
          </includes>
      </artifactSet>
      <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
      <relocations>
          <relocation>
            <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
            <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
          </relocation>
      </relocations>
      <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
      </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thank you for this, it worked :)
how does this renaming of packageof classes work ? how spark now knows to pick these classes from the classpath Not that of Hadoop which is 11.0.2 ?

Comment: When using relocations, shade will rewrite your classes to use a new package named 'repackaged.com.google.common' and will put your version of guava under that package. The version of guava in hadoop will still use the com.google.common package and will not conflict with your uber jar as it will no longer contain classes in that package.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc